# Timestep multiple items dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, velocity, timestep

I have such dataframe:

| product1 | product2 | product3 | product4 | product5 | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| straws | orange | melon | chair | bread | 1 |
| melon | milk | book | coffee | cake | 2 |
| bread | bananas | juice | chair | book | 3 |
| straws | coffee | cake | milk | orange | 4 |

I need to have the time step per items.

Example :

| TimesProduct1 | TimesProduct2 | TimesProduct3 | Timesproduct4 | Timesproduct5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 |

df.diff() unfortunatly doesn't work in that way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It is really unclear what you are wanting to do.

Comment: ok so i have for example a first client at time 1 who bought straws, then at time 4 another one bought this product. The time step is 3, it's the difference between the product apparence per time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "product1":["straws", "melon", "bread", "straws"],
        "product2":["orange", "milk", "bananas", "coffee"],
        "product3":["melon", "book", "juice", "cake"],
        "product4":["chair", "coffee", "chair", "milk"],
        "product5":["bread", "cake", "book", "orange"],
        "time":[1,2,3,4],
    }
)
```

**solution**

```
result = (
    df.melt(id_vars="time")
    .groupby("value")
    .apply(lambda d: d.sort_values("time").eval("diff = time.diff()"))
    .pivot(index="time", columns="variable", values="diff")
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

**solution 2 (for pandas bug workaround)**

```
def make_diff_column(df):
    df = df.sort_values("time")
    df["diff"] = df["time"].diff()
    return df


result = (
    df.melt(id_vars="time")
    .groupby("value")
    .apply(make_diff_column)
    .pivot(index="time", columns="variable", values="diff")
    .fillna(0)
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: i have a message error :'unshable type:'series'. on this line ".apply(lambda d: d.sort_values("time").eval("diff = time.diff()"))"

Comment: I've tried so hard to work on it but it's a very important task. I have another very similar to this one. Imagine  I have a camera in a forest, and per day I have over 10 differents kind of animals crossing. All i need is the overlap between days or more exactly the dt. With over 100 differents species, overlap is a very important aspect.

Comment: What version of `pandas` are you using?

Comment: the version of colab, it's 1.3.5 version

Comment: We're using different versions of pandas which no doubt is the cause of lack of reproducibility.  See if the Solution 2 will work for you?

Comment: Riley thanks a lot for your help, it definetly works. Bravo

Comment: Hi Riley, i know it's uncanny to reach out in that way but i need your help on my new question in my prodfile. I have hard times using pandas for this problem and i hope you could help. Thanks a lot.